# An application of Fatou's lemma

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\{f_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a family of real positive measurable function on $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$  such that $0 \leq f_0 \leq f_1 \leq \ldots $. If $\lim f_k = f$ on $D$ then $$\lim \int_D f_k(t)dt = \int_D \lim f_k(t) dt = \int_D f(t) dt.$$

Is this proof is right? And is there another way for the solution? Thank you!

PROOF. Let $\{g_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of non-negative measurable functions on $D$. If $\lim_{k \to +\infty} g_k = g$ then we have
$$\int_D g = \int_D \lim g_k = \int_D \liminf_{k\to +\infty}( g_k )\leq \liminf_{k \to + \infty} \left(\int_D g_k \right) = \lim_{k \to + \infty} \int_D g_k.$$
And then 
$$\int_D g \leq \lim_{k \to + \infty} \int_D g_k.$$
Note that $0 \leq f_0 \leq f_1 \leq \ldots \leq f$ on $D$. Then

$\bullet$ Let us consider the family $\{f - f_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$. We have $\lim_{k \to +\infty } (f - f_k ) = 0$ and $f - f_k$ is a non-negative function for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then
$$ 0 \leq \lim_{k \to + \infty} \int_D (f - f_k)$$ or $$ \lim_{k \to + \infty} \int_D f_k \leq \int_D f.$$

$\bullet$ Let us consider the family $\{f_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ then we have
$$\int_D f \leq \lim_{k \to + \infty} \int_D f_k .$$
This implies that
$$\lim_{k \to + \infty} \int_D f_k  = \int_D \, f \ .$$

Comment: In general, in Fatou's lemma you are not allowed to assume that the integrals converge (you have to stick to $\liminf$). Of course it is so in your application.

Comment: @ Michał Miśkiewicz Yes, of course, the functions are measurable functions on $D$. Thank you, I added! Do you have another proof?

Comment: @mathJuan [Do you have another proof?]---> You can add this in the question frame (because as stated your text is not a question)

Comment: @ Sir Gerard: Yes, I am interested in this question, and I added them before the proof. Thank you Sir.

Comment: Let me rephrase my previous comment: in the standard statement of Fatou's lemma the sequence $\int_D g_k$ is not assumed to be convergent, hence the use of $\liminf$. Of course you can alter the statement so that the convergence is an additional assumption.

Answer (score 1):

What you did here is a proof of [Lebesgue's monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) using [Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou's_lemma). Each of them can be derived directly from the definition of Lebesgue integral, you can also show the latter using the former. All these three proofs I've just mentioned can be found on Wikipedia.

And yes, your proof seems all right.

Comment: Thank you so much for your hints. But I don't understand how do you use the former to proving them?

Comment: I meant that you could show Fatou's lemma using the monotone convergence theorem.